# Android Activity private variable between functions

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I want my app to take photo (not with intent). 
I want my activity A.class to take picture and give to an other activity B.class the absolutePath() of my picture in putExtra of intent to call B.Class.

Here my code

**ANDROID CODE**

```
public class A extends Activity  {
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
    private Camera camera=null;
    private boolean inPreview=false;
    private boolean cameraConfigured=false;
    protected static final String TAG = "DEBUG_TAG";
    protected Throwable e;
    private File pictureFile;
    private String picturePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capture);
        SurfaceView preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView_camera);
        previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        TextView capturer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView_capturer);
        capturer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
(L.88)          call_next_activity(v);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (inPreview) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
        inPreview=false;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        camera=Camera.open();
        startPreview();
    }

    private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
        if (camera!=null && previewHolder.getSurface()!=null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback", "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast.makeText(capture.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (!cameraConfigured) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                parameters.set("rotation", 90);
                Camera.Size Previewsize=getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(Previewsize.width, Previewsize.height);
                Camera.Size PictureSize = getBestPictureSize(width, height, parameters);
                parameters.setPictureSize(PictureSize.width, PictureSize.height);
                parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                cameraConfigured=true;
            }
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
                if (result==null) {
                    result=size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;
                    if (newArea>resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return(result);
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPictureSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (size.width>=width && size.height>=height) {
                if (result==null) {
                    result=size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;
                    if (newArea>resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return(result);
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        if (cameraConfigured && camera!=null) {
            camera.startPreview();
            inPreview=true;
        }
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        String NewFolder = "/TEST";
        String StorageDirectory;
        StorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(StorageDirectory + NewFolder);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Jours de Chefs", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            } else {
                mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
            }
        }

        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE).format(new Date());

        File photo = new File(StorageDirectory + NewFolder, "Full_TEST_" + date + ".jpg");
        return photo;       
    }

    public void call_next_activity(View v) {

        // ----- HERE I HAVE EXCEPTION -----//
        // When i want to call picturePath or pictureFile, i get Exception :
        // NullPointerException
(L.246) if (!picturePath.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(capture.this, "CA MARCHE !!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(capture.this, "CA MARCHE PAS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            chemin_acces_photo = pictureFile.getPath();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            // ----- HERE TOAST SHOW ME RIGHT PATH ----- //
            // NO EXCEPTION, NO BUG, EVERYTHING IS OKAY
            Toast.makeText(capture.this, pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            initPreview(width, height);
            startPreview();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // no-op
        }
    };  
}
```

Everything work great, but when i want to call pictureFile.getAbsolutePath() I have this error :

**LOGCAT CODE**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14165): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.capture.call_next_activity(capture.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.capture$3.onClick(capture.java:88)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone explain me why my pictureFile == NULL ?

---

**EDIT 1** : 
Melquiades answer

> It's because camera.takePicture() is asynchronous. You have:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    call_next_activity(v); //<----------here picturePath is not yet initialised
}
```

> So when you call takePicture() above, it immediately returns and call_next_activity() is > called, but picturePath is not yet set.
>
> Move your call_next_activity() code to your mPicture() callback, AFTER picturePath is set.

Nice explanation, but now i've got new problem : 
my call_next_activity(v) code was an example, in this function, i want to change activity, then my real code if :

**ANDROID CODE**

```
public void call_next_activity(v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, next_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("image_path", picturePath);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can't put my call_next_activity() code into mPicture Callback because of my *this* will not be my view, but will be *Camera.PictureCallback(){}*

Any idea ?

---

**EDIT 2** : **ANSWER**
Follow Melquiades Edit, just remove call_next_activity(v) function, 
write call_next_activity code at the end of onPictureTaken() function :

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(capture.this, pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    // ----- call_next_activity code here ----- //
    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), next_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("image_path", pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

PS : i delete my picturePath (string) variable, and change picturePath by pictureFile.getAbsolutePath().

Thank you all!

Comment: You need context, so either declare private Context context and set it in onCreate(), and then use instead of this, or use getApplicationContext() instead of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because camera.takePicture() is asynchronous. You have:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    call_next_activity(v); //<----------here picturePath is not yet initialised
}
```

So when you call takePicture() above, it immediately returns and call_next_activity() is called, but picturePath is not yet set.

Move your call_next_activity() code to your mPicture() callback, AFTER picturePath is set.

EDIT:

Declare

```
private Context context;
```

in your A class, then set it on onCreate() after setContentView():

```
context = this;
```

And finally, use it to set your intent:

```
public void call_next_activity(v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (context, next_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("image_path", picturePath);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), next_activity.class);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, next_activity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code in question, I think you are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` because your `String` variable `picturePath` doesn't have any value. please initialise some value to it.

Hope it will help you

Comment: I think Melquiades answer is better... I don't want to initialise my variable with "foo". I want my variable == null at the beginning...

BTW, Thank you for your answer !

Comment: i don't have any problem if your problem is solved by using his method. @locobastos